# How do I install a python package from a .py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, jupyter

I am using Jupyter notebook and is in desperate need of installing the "copy" package.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html

I found the github link as a py file:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/copy.py

The standard method of "!pip install copy" doesn't work.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement copy (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for copy

Thanks

Comment: I doubt this. This is part of the standard library, if that's not there, your interpreter is broken.

Comment: "I am using Jupyter notebook" -> I guess the cell doing the import is not run.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to install the copy module because it is part of the standard library.
Just use `import copy`

Comment: Okay, thanks. I imported and used the copy.copy function successfully.